# Testing function on ViewModel with LiveData

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have the following kotlin class to be tested, the class is a viewmodel of android architecture with a livedata.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var myList: ArrayList<MyData>
    val listLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<MyData>>()
    ...

    private fun publish(toBePublished: List<MyData>) {
        listLiveData.postValue(toBePublished)
    } 

    fun sort(sortCriteria: SortCriteria) {
        // ...  Business logic to be tested
        // ...  This method works with myList
        publish(sorted)
    }
    ...
}


class MyViewModelTest {
    @Test
    fun sort() {
        val myList =  ......
        val viewModel = Mockito.mock(MyViewModel::class.java)
        FieldSetter.setField(viewModel, viewModel.javaClass.getDeclaredField("myList"), myList)

        viewModel.sort(sortCriteria)

        assert ???
    }
}
```

How can I check the result of the sort method?

Comment: What do you want to test? MyViewModel class?  Is ServerProViewModelTest the test of MyViewModel? What is the SortCriteria object? What is FieldSetter? Please, add more information, thanks

Comment: What's the sort criteria ?

Comment: @ManuelMato ok, I correct the question. The correct test class is "MyViewModelTest". I want to test the sort method in the MyViewModel class.
SortCriteria is an enum handled in business logic.
FieldSetter is a function of Mockito to set a private field.
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.0/org/mockito/internal/util/reflection/FieldSetter.html

Comment: Ok, I think this approach is not correct because you are mocking your subject under test.  So, the ViewModel must be a real instance and only mock your business object to return a fake data and then check the livedata value.  So the name method under test must be something like "verify listLiveData value when sorted method with full list is called then the result must be a sorted list".  It is easier if you inject your business object by constructor, because you con mock it, add the behavior and then instantiate your viewmodel with the business mock.

Comment: I'm refactoring my code to move the business logic to another class that is testable.